# Chart in html with javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a javascript file (jquery.visualize.plugin.js) that displays a chart.

First, I display in a .aspx page with a repeater control. So I have this :[image]

And and just below I have the graphic. It works well in .aspx page.

Now, I would like display in HTML page but it doesn't work.

Here is my Html page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.visualize.plugin.js"></script>
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('table').visualize({ type: 'line' }).appendTo('body');
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<headertemplate>
    <table id="table_campaigns" class="display">
        <caption style="font-size:20px">Statistiek 2 : per productgroep</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <th>2010</th>
            <th>2011</th>
            <th>2012</th>
            <th>2013</th>
            <th>2014</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</headertemplate>
<itemtemplate>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</itemtemplate>
<footertemplate>
    </table>
</footertemplate>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my .aspx page that works well :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableViewState="false" CodeBehind="Page_Statistiek_2.aspx.cs" Inherits="PageWebSage100.Page_Statistiek_2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title></title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/jquery.visualize.plugin.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Css/base.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Css/jquery.visualize.plugin.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('table').visualize({ type: 'line' }).appendTo('body');
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCreated="Repeater1_ItemCreated">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table>
            <caption style="font-size:20px">Statistiek 2 : per productgroep</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <th scope="col"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="Ym4"></asp:Label></th>
                    <th scope="col"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="Ym3"></asp:Label></th>
                    <th scope="col"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="Ym2"></asp:Label></th>
                    <th scope="col"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="Ym1"></asp:Label></th>
                    <th scope="col"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="Ym0"></asp:Label></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>                       
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align:left" scope="row"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Interventie") %></th>
                    <td><%# Math.Round(((PageWebSage100.WebServiceSage100.Statistic_2)Container.DataItem).Sum[0],2) %></td>
                    <td><%# Math.Round(((PageWebSage100.WebServiceSage100.Statistic_2)Container.DataItem).Sum[1],2)%></td>
                    <td><%# Math.Round(((PageWebSage100.WebServiceSage100.Statistic_2)Container.DataItem).Sum[2],2)%></td>
                    <td><%# Math.Round(((PageWebSage100.WebServiceSage100.Statistic_2)Container.DataItem).Sum[3],2)%></td>
                    <td><%# Math.Round(((PageWebSage100.WebServiceSage100.Statistic_2)Container.DataItem).Sum[4],2)%></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I just added the script in the head tag.
Ps : I use a dataTable in HTML page.

What's wrong?

[image]

Comment: What is the rendered HTML from the Server Control?

Comment: I edit my post, you can see my html page. You want to know that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use parts of ASP.NET Repeater control in HTML page. This is not going to work since Repeater works only in ASPX pages (with corresponding code-behind to handle databinding and/or rendering (i.e. `Repeater1_ItemCreated`).

If you want to display content of that page in an HTML page - you have couple choices - for example use IFRAME and display original ASPX page in the IFRAME within HTML page or use jQuery `.load()` method to load content of ASPX page into container DIV within the HTML page.

As an alternative if you want to reuse table HTML table already rendered by Repeater - just copy/paste table element (table, tbody, tr, th, td elements in their entirety) but to not include any HeaderTemplate, ItemTemplate, FooterTemplate tags.

Comment: is it possible to load the chart from javascript file ithout using aspx page?

Comment: @Jayce yes, this jQuery plugin runs on client-side, it does not require ASPX. As long as you can provide an HTML table to it - ordinary HTML page is fine. In your particular case table is generated via ASPX repeater control. There're other ways of obtaining data e.g. making AJAX call to the server or simpler (as I said in my answer) use `.load()` method to load HTML table from a separate page

Comment: Ok I'll see it tomorrow, I'll let you know

Comment: I added this : <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#includedContent").load("HtmlChart.html");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="includedContent"></div>
</body>
</html>

HtmlChart.html :

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('table').visualize({ type: 'line' }).appendTo('body');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="table_campaigns" class="display">
...

It displays my HtlmChart.html that has a table but the chart doesn't displays. I don't understand.

Comment: Don't load .HTML page into your DIV. Load the original .ASPX page.